# Simulating actions by Overloading POST vs Embedding in the URI

Tags: rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am currently reading Restful Java & Restful Web Services and have a style question about REST where these two books seem to disagree.  Specifically what to do about changing the state of the resource.

Restful Java has an example of an order that can be cancelled.  It presents adding cancelled=true to the representation in a PUT request to make a state transfer.  So you would have something like this.

```
PUT /orders/333 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/xml

<order id="333">
  <...>
  <cancelled>true</cancelled>
</order>
```

Then it proposes instead doing it as a separate uri embedded in the order (or as a Link: http header)

```
PUT /orders/333 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/xml

<order id="333">
  <...>
  <link rel="cancel" href="http://example.com/orders/333/cancelled">
</order>
```

This made sense to me, until I read the Restful Web Services book which seems to fall on the side of posting the cancelled=true to an overloaded POST.

I tend to like the /orders/333/cancelled because I can easily expose that there is a way to take this action using links, I am just curious as to if this is a good practice or if there is a better way?

Thanks,
Ransom

Comment: Both ways I think are fine, however, I also use the `links` functionality and I would probably do it accordingly to your way, but I don't know if I would use `links` like you use it. Perhaps `<link rel="self cancel" href="http://example.com/orders/333/cancelled">` is better or just `self`? `self` is of course a reference to the order number.

Comment: On second thought use `self cancel` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "problem" with creating a "cancelled" URL is that the act of cancelling an order isn't technically a resource.  Meaning that the cancellation isn't its own resource - it's simply a way of modifying the existing order resource.  If you want to be RESTful, then you should avoid this path and support PUT with the cancelled property inside the body, or you could support a partial update with PATCH (although this HTTP verb is less widely supported than PUT).

Another option would be to create an "operation" resource.  That operation would define the kinds of things you can do to your order, e.g. cancel, duplicate, close, etc.  But this tends to be heavy weight and potentially unnecessary, unless you're starting to get into bulk operations.  Then this technique is pretty powerful and the only way I've found to RESTfully model bulk ops.

Of course, you can always ignore the purists and say you don't care whether or not your service is RESTful.  If all you want is to expose this verb with a raw HTTP interface, well, that's up to you.

Comment: An "operation" or processing resource can simply exist to perform the sole function of cancelling a specific resource.  Obviously a naive implementation could be tedious but there are plenty of ways to avoid that pain.

Answer (score 0):

What the URI looks like is far less important than the `rel="Cancel"` part, that's all the client should really care about.  If you want to avoid people saying you are putting verbs in your URL, then just change your URI to

```
http://example.com/orders/333/cancellor
```

or

```
http://example.com/cancellor?target=/orders/333
```

Regarding the alternative approach suggested, personally I'm not a big fan of the PUT to change status.  For status updates, I like to POST to a filtered status collection.

```
POST http://example.com/orders/cancelled
<order>...</order>
```